# robot web tools -> set fixed frame for camera

Tags: ros, ros3djs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

is it possible to rviz-like specify the fixed-frame for the camera in ros3d.js?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187371/robot-web-tools--%3E-set-fixed-frame-for-camera/) by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7555 on 2014-07-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should have a global TFClient object that most ros3djs objects take in as a parameter. This object can be initialized with an alternative fixed frame, e.g., http://wiki.ros.org/ros3djs/Tutorials/VisualizingInteractiveMarkers#CA-3c28fc37578db0ccb1aa845adfa83e6d333d7fb3_35

---

Originally posted by [rtoris288](https://answers.ros.org/users/982/rtoris288/) with karma: 1173 on 2014-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2014-07-23**:
That should do the trick thanks!! Only thing that stays on the fixed frame (not depending which) is the ROS3d.Grid but it can be connected to a frame via ROS3d.SceneNode and then also behaves properly....